Snowflake - problem when using Bind variable
I had the following error when trying to use the bind variable like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE db.schema.sp_1(table_name VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    full_table_name VARCHAR DEFAULT CONCAT('db.schema.',:table_name);
    select_statement VARCHAR;
    result_select_statement RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    select_statement := 'SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0)) flg_sum FROM ' || IDENTIFIER(:full_table_name);
result_select_statement := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement);

    LET c1 CURSOR FOR result_select_statement;
    FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
...


Bind variable for object "full_table_name" not set

Any thoughts?

You only need to use a colon before the variable name in a SQL statement; you are using the variable in a string. This is documented here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding

@NickW i leave it as: select_statement := 'SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0)) flg_sum FROM ' || :full_table_name; as per you said, is a string, the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is going be fine, thanks

stepping though the code:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_1(table_name VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    full_table_name VARCHAR DEFAULT CONCAT('db.schema.', :table_name);
begin
    return full_table_name;
end;
$$;

call sp_1('aa');




SP_1




db.schema.aa



happy, good. One of Nick's point is this could be:
full_table_name VARCHAR DEFAULT CONCAT('db.schema.', table_name);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_2(table_name VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    full_table_name VARCHAR DEFAULT CONCAT('db.schema.',:table_name);
    select_statement VARCHAR;
begin
    select_statement := 'SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0)) flg_sum FROM ' || IDENTIFIER(:full_table_name);
    return select_statement;
end;
$$;


Error: Bind variable for object "full_table_name" not set (line 20)

so this could be changed to
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_3(table_name VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    full_table_name VARCHAR DEFAULT CONCAT('db.schema.',:table_name);
    select_statement VARCHAR;
begin
    select_statement := 'SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0)) flg_sum FROM ' || full_table_name;
    return select_statement;
end;
$$;

and thus:
call sp_3('aa');




SP_3




SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0)) flg_sum FROM db.schema.aa



so next some fake data, in my test.test:
create table aa(flag number);
insert into aa values(1),(3);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_5(table_name VARCHAR)
RETURNS table(text) NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    full_table_name VARCHAR DEFAULT CONCAT('test.test.',:table_name);
    select_statement VARCHAR;
    result_select_statement RESULTSET;
begin
    select_statement := 'SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0))::text flg_sum FROM ' || full_table_name;
    result_select_statement := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement);
    return table(result_select_statement);
end;
$$;

call sp_5('aa');




FLG_SUM




4



Now if you want to use IDENTIFIER to make things safe, it needs to be passed a string, so to take your results in the string building of select_statement then the quotes need escaping:
aka if it's quote escaped this SQL is generated:
SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0))::text flg_sum FROM IDENTIFIER(test.test.aa)

and that is invalid:

SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 54 unexpected 'test'.

and needs to be:
SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0))::text flg_sum FROM IDENTIFIER('test.test.aa')

thus the SP needs to be:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_6(table_name VARCHAR)
RETURNS table(text) NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    full_table_name VARCHAR DEFAULT CONCAT('test.test.',:table_name);
    select_statement VARCHAR;
    result_select_statement RESULTSET;
begin
    select_statement := 'SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0))::text flg_sum FROM IDENTIFIER(''' || full_table_name || ''')';
    result_select_statement := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement);
    return table(result_select_statement);
end;
$$;

call sp_6('aa');




FLG_SUM




4




Thank you very much Simeon, yeah i ended up using the full_table_name like this: select_statement := 'SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0))::text flg_sum FROM ' || :full_table_name; . I need to remove the ':' before the variable?

Why not simply use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query USING (variable)? There is no need for string concatenation, handling multiple ' etc. -Sample Code

select_statement := 'SELECT SUM(NVL(flag,0))::text flg_sum FROM IDENTIFIER(?)'; and result_select_statement := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement USING (full_table_name));

I was planning on going somewhere like that, when I first started answering the question, and then got tired. so cheers for adding the details.
